# Apple Dashboard Widget setTimeout Not Working

Tags: javascript, widget, dashboard

I'm working on a calendar based dashboard widget that I want to automatically updated at the start of a new day. However, I can't seem to get it to actually update. It seems to work fine running in a browser. I've also tried manually entering the setTimeout delay to something much shorter (like 1 or 2 minutes) and that seems to work.

This is the code I have:

```
function Calendar() {
    var _self = this;

    this.daytimer = null;
    this.daytimerAction = function() {
        _self.updateCurrentDate();
    }
    this.resetDaytimer();
}

Calendar.prototype.resetDaytimer = function() {
    var today = new Date(),
        tomorrow = new Date();

    if (this.daytimer) {
        clearTimeout(this.daytimer);
        this.daytimer = null;
    }

    tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate() + 1);
    tomorrow.setHours(0);
    tomorrow.setMinutes(0);
    tomorrow.setSeconds(1);

    this.daytimer = setTimeout(this.daytimerAction, tomorrow.getTime() - today.getTime());
};

Calendar.prototype.updateCurrentDate = function() {
    // Run code to update the day display

    this.resetDaytimer();
};
```

Any thoughts? The only thing I can think of is that dashboard is pausing/cancelling the setTimeout when dashboard isn't running. Maybe there is a way to reset the timeout when dashboard is reactivated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Dashboard_ProgTopics/Articles/Events.html) outlines the `widget.onshow` event that I can use to restart the timer as well as call `updateCurrentDate()` directly. There is also a `widget.onhide` event that can be used to pause the timer.